# How to change name of file to upper case and extension to lower case?

Tags: windows, rename, batch-rename

I have some files as shown in below:

input: ObjectName.TXT

I want to convert name of the file to Upper case while extention should be in lower case by using batch file. please help me how to convert my object name as below

output: OBJECTNAME.txt

I need to convert object names in windows for using in Solaris and Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a batch script but a PowerShell script:

```
# Get all items in the current directory
Get-ChildItem | %{
    # Construct a new file name
    $newFilename = ($_.BaseName.ToUpper())+($_.Extension.ToLower());

    # Move the file
    Move-Item $_ $newFilename
}
```

Comment: I think you have `ToLower` and `ToUpper` the wrong way around looking at the question ...

Comment: Correct, rima submitted a change and I accepted it. Should be the right way around now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ReNamer's](http://www.den4b.com/?x=products&product=renamer) "Case" renaming rule:

> Case: All upper case (skip extension), Extension lower case

You can save your rules as a preset and use it to rename files/folders via command line and also in a batch file, e.g. `ReNamer.exe /rename <preset> <files-and-directories>`

[image: ReNamer - name upper case, extension lower case]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry because i cant comment but for do it in one liner you do :

```
Get-ChildItem | % { Move-Item -Path $_ -Destination (($_.BaseName.ToUpper())+($_.Extension.ToLower())) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternate way of doing this:

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName.ToUpper() + $_.Extension.ToLower()}
```